# Log the time and other stats taken by a command in bash by default

Tags: bash, time, execute-command

Is there  way in Ubuntu to log by default all the statistics of the ran commands like time taken, memory used, cache utilization etc.

I have installed audit and used aureport  command but unable to figure out how to log the duration for which each command ran.

Comment: Automatic way, no, at least not that I know of. There is `time` shell built-in command and `/usr/bin/time` ( which I personally prefer because it is more detailed by default ) , which you can use before each command, like `/usr/bin/time ls` or `/usr/bin/time lsblk`

Comment: @Serg I know of the time command but I dont want to use it each time., all commands have to be timed seperately in  a log

Comment: Well, as i said, there's no automatic tool, at least not to my knowledge.